# Python: issue when using vars() dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following snippet:

```
a, b = 1, 2
params = ['a', 'b']
res = {p: vars()[p] for p in params}
```

Which gives me `KeyError: 'a'` whereas the following code works fine:

```
a, b = 1, 2
params = ['a', 'b']
res = {}
for p in params:
    res[p] = vars()[p]
```

What's the difference here?

Comment: You're asking because you're curious, not because you rely on `vars()`/`locals()` in your actual programs, right?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: now after you've asked I'd say solely due to curiosity :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) without any argument acts like `locals()` and since a dictionary comprehension has its own scope it has no variable named `a` or `b`.

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) here. Without any argument it will execute in [LEGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) manner, or specify `globals()` dict explicitly to `eval`:

```
>>> res = {p: eval(p) for p in params}
>>> res
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

---

But then again the correct way will be to create a dictionary from the start if you want to access variables using their names.

Comment: What would be the way to fix it if I don't want to go through a multi-line loop?

Comment: The best way to fix it is to avoid messing with `vars()`/`locals()` altogether, because they will give you issues such as this one.

Comment: I only use `vars()` with `format`: it's just too attractive to write `'foo {bar} baz {spam}'.format(**vars())` rather than `.format(bar=bar,spam=spam)`.  But it does go wrong inside a comprehension. @TigerhawkT3 what would you recommend as the Pythonic alternative to my `.format(**vars())` code?

Comment: How about `'foo {} baz {}'.format(bar, spam)`? The typing effort is O(n) instead of O(1) (a comma to separate each element instead of an unpacked dictionary) with an intersection at n=8, but it works in a comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

Its because of that in your code `vars` returns a dictionary contains the **local** variables.actually based on documentation :

> Without an argument, [vars()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) acts like [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) .

see the following example :

```
>>> def a():
...   print vars()
... 
>>> a()
{}
```

As you can see we have not any local variable within function `a` so vars returns an empty dictionary.

And in your case as a more pythonic way you can create a dictionary of your objects :

```
d={'a':1,'b': 2,'params' : ['a', 'b']}
example_list : ['a', 'b']
res = {p: d[p] for p in example_list}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems Python makes a closure in dictionary comprehension (say, `dictcomp`)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
KeyError: 'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `vars()` in the for loop performs as the second code you gave.

```
# come out with {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
res = {p: v for p, v in vars().iteritems() if p in params}
res = {'a': vars()['a'], 'b': vars()['b']}
```

We can figure out the new `locals/vars` within `for` loop in dict comprehension:

```
>>> {i: list(vars().viewkeys()) if i == 0 else list(vars().viewvalues()) for i in range(2)}
{0: ['i', '.0'], 1: [1, <listiterator at 0x6fffe458550>]}
>>> {list(vars().viewkeys())[i]: list(vars().viewvalues())[i] for i in range(2)}
{'.0': <listiterator at 0x6fffe458710>, 'i': 0}
```